# Insert JSON data into mysql using Python Django framework

Tags: python, json, django

Declared name,mobile,age in models.py and same fields added in the database also.How to insert JSON data into mysql database using Python DJango framework.Tried this but not working.

```
js_data = session.query(tbl_users).create({'name' : 'mmmmm','mobile':'123456','age':'35'})
session.add(js_data)
session.commit()
```

Comment: What does "not working" entail? errors? invalid results? Please read [ask]

Comment: Exception Type:AttributeError
Exception Value: 'Query' object has no attribute 'create'

Comment: This isn't even vaguely how you write Django code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, please choose a better title and tags for your question. This question isn't really about JSON, it's about inserting values into the database. Even more importantly, your code does not appear to be Django at all; it seems to be SQLAlchemy. So asking about JSON and Django is unlikely to get you much help.

Now that we know it's SQLAlchemy, we can look at the [documentation for how to add objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html?highlight=create#adding-new-objects). There's no reference to `query` or `create` there at all. It seems like it should be:

```
js_data = tbl_users(**{'name' : 'mmmmm','mobile':'123456','age':'35'})
session.add(js_data)
session.commit()
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option to solve your problem (insert JSON data into mysql) is to install and use this special package:
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/json-fields/